# How to XMLRPC Client of another node in C++

Tags: ros, pid, xmlrpc, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I'm trying to get the PID of another nodes running ROS in order to monitor the memory and CPU usage. To do so, I get the name of all the nodes:

```
// Get node names
std::vector<std::string> nodes;
ros::master::getNodes(nodes);
```

Afterwards I go node by node getting the URI:

```
// Get URI of the node
XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue args, result, payload;
args.setSize(2);
args[0] = "caller_name";
args[1] = "node_name";
ros::master::execute("lookupNode", args, result, payload, true);
```

But can't get the getPid to work, the execute function always returns false.

```
// Make new client of node
std::string uri = result[2];
XmlRpc::XmlRpcClient* client =
ros::XMLRPCManager::instance()->getXMLRPCClient(ros::master::getHost(), ros::master::getPort(), uri.c_str());

// Get PID of the node
XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue request, response;
request.setSize(1);
request[0] = "node_name";
client->execute("getPid", request, response);
```

The "getXMLRPCClient" function seems to always return a client even if not already existent. The "client->execute" can return false on several ocations, so I don't have any clue how to debug this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363029/how-to-xmlrpc-client-of-another-node-in-c++/) by [marinamrr](https://answers.ros.org/users/60202/marinamrr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2020-10-07

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.The following method worked for me.

```
  // Make new client of node
  int port = get_port(static_cast<std::string>(result[2]));
  XmlRpc::XmlRpcClient* xclient = ros::XMLRPCManager::instance()->getXMLRPCClient(ros::master::getHost(), port, "/");

  // Get PID of the node
  XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue request, response;
  xclient->execute("getPid", request, response);
```

I needed the port to be the number of the node I wanted to manipulate, not the number of the master. get_port is a function that looks like this, for example

```
int get_port(std::string uri)
{
  int port = 0;
  bool pre_colon = false;
  bool start_number = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < uri.size(); i++)
  {
    if (uri[i] == ':')
    {
      pre_colon = true;
    }
    else
    {
      if (pre_colon || start_number)
      {
        if (uri[i] >= '0' && uri[i] <= '9')
        {
          start_number = true;
          port = port * 10 + (uri[i] - '0');
        }
        else if (start_number)
        {
          break;
        }
      }
      pre_colon = false;
    }
  }

  return port;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2021-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aravindsaiUR](https://answers.ros.org/users/60815/aravindsaiur/) on 2021-05-19**:
Be sure to close the client created by the XmlRpc::XmlRpcClient, since it opens a socket for every client created. In case you run this in loop, you could get "Too many files opened" error or "Error:24" especially in linux. Since for each client a socket is created and sockets are defined as file descriptors in linux. This will be a memory leak. So always close an opened client after processing. Releasing the client connection is recommended.

```
ros::XMLRPCManager::instance()->releaseXMLRPCClient(xclient);
```

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-05-19**:
Thank you very much. I learned a lot.